# Abrir URL especifica desde datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datepicker

estoy trabajando con jquery datepicker y quede trabado en un punto y no lo puedo resolver, por eso recurro a uds. en el codigo que les dejo a continuacion logré que desde un datepicker abra una URL, pero el problema es que cada fecha que se selecciona en el datepicker siempre abre lo mismo, yo necesito que para cada fecha que se elije se abra una pagina que tenga relacion con esa fecha en particular, es decir, del dia 23, datos de ese dia, del dia 10, datos de ese dia y asi sucesivamente. Sera eso posible ?

```js
$ = jQuery.noConflict();
 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){
       $("#datepicker").datepicker({
   closeText: 'Cerrar',
   prevText: '< Ant',
   nextText: 'Sig >',
   currentText: 'Hoy',
   monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
   monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
   dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
   dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Juv','Vie','Sáb'],
   dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sá'], 
   firstDay: 1,
   showOn: "button",
   buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
   buttonImageOnly: true,
   buttonText: "Select date"      
});
});
});
function myFunc(){
    var dateData = $("#datepicker").val();

    if(dateData != '' ){

        var url = "https://agencialareal.com.ar/cabezas-11-05-20/";
        window.open(url);

    }
}
```

```html
<p>Date: <input type="text" name="fecha_entrada" id="datepicker" onchange="myFunc();" placeholder="Sorteo del día..."></p>
```

Comment: Explica mejor tu problema y pon más ejemplos sobre lo que necesitas hacer vs lo que ya tienes hecho.

Comment: Puntualmente lo que necesito es que desde el datepicker al seleccionar una fecha muestre resultados de esa fecha (resultados de sorteos de loteria), lo que logre hacer hasta ahora es que pueda abrir cualquier url sin problemas al seleccionar una fecha, pero el problema es que siempre abre la misma ...

Comment: Bueno, es que lo que hagas cuando recibas la fecha seleccionada ya es cosa diferente, datepicker no hace cosas así pero puedes tomar la fecha que se selecciona y con eso ejecutar alguna acción. Me imagino que la acción que tú haces es tal vez hacer una petición ajax, abrir un vínculo o hacer cualquier cosa, ¿es correcto? Por otro lado, ¿qué haces cuando se selecciona la fecha? ¿Abres una nueva pesteña con alguna url personalizada o algo así?

Comment: En realidad lo que logre seria solo un incentivo para creer que lo que busco podria funcionar desde un datepicker, posiblemente sea ajax lo que me termine de solucionar todo, pero soy muy novato en esto asique no se hasta donde llegare, y respondiendo a tu pregunta, solo busco que al seleccionar una fecha me muestre info de un url determinado, es decir cada fecha del calendario deberia estar relacionada a un url distinto